# mac app store productbuild error while archiving application

Tags: macos, app-store, productbuild

I use productbuild to archive my application for submitting to app store. I run this command in the terminal:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/productbuild   --component /Ahmed/QtWorkMac/AlMosaly2-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_0_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/AlMosaly2.app /Applications /Ahmed --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Nourayn Media Group"
```

but an error occurs that's:

```
productbuild: error: Cannot write product to "/Ahmed". (The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `--sign` before `--component`. Then, after the path to the app bundle, you should give the path where you want to save the package. You have `/Applications /Ahmed` which is not what it's expecting.